# How can I store my oil pastels?

Tags: oil-pastels, storage

When I was in junior high school (long time ago), I won a drawing contest and the prize was a set of oil pastels. Never used them much over the years, but I ran into them recently.

Someone, either me or my parents at the time, threw out the original packaging and placed all my pastels in a freezer bag. While they were protected from the elements they were not protected from themselves.

Assuming the original packaging is lost, what storage strategy can I consider for my pastels. I am thinking about container as well as long term storage concerns. For instance: How is temperature a factor?

Answer (score 8):

So the main considerations for storing oil pastels are:

- The individual pastels are kept separate, so that they do not bleed into one another
- They are kept reasonably cool (room temperature, ~20ºC is fine)

If the latter is a problem, just keep them in the fridge (although you'll want to allow them to warm up a bit before using them).

As for the former, if you've lost the original packaging, that is a bit of a pain. [Artbin](http://www.artbin.com/en/crafts/products/storage%20essentials) make art supplies storage boxes of many varieties, there will probably be at least one type of box that fits your needs. There are also plenty of places that sell slightly more expensive wooden pastel boxes - these might be overkill though.

In a pinch, the [tray from a box of chocolate fingers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qly4n.jpg) might do too.

Comment: I was fishing for idea like the chocolate fingers boxes.  Thanks. For as often I am using them that works well for me.